# Append and increment hash in Ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this hash :

```
hash = {:title=>"blabla", :content=>"blabla", :mark=>40}
```

In a loop I want to increment it with another pair of the same key => value objects.

What I want to have looks like this in PHP

```
    hash = array(
            0 => array(
              'title' => 'blabla',
              'content' => 'blabla',
              'mark' => 50,
            ),
            1 => array(
              'title' => 'blabla',
              'content' => 'blabla',
              'mark' => 50,
            )
     );
```

And to have that I would loop like that

```
foreach ($elements as $element) {
   $hash[] = array('title' => $element['title'],
                   'content' => $element['blabla'],
                   'mark' => $element['mark']
             );
}
```

The `[]` after the variable name, auto increments the array in php, but it doesn't seem to act the same way with Ruby.

The expected Ruby ouput would be the following :

```
hash = {
                {
                  'title' => 'blabla',
                  'content' => 'blabla',
                  'mark' => 50,
               },
                {
                  'title' => 'blabla',
                  'content' => 'blabla',
                  'mark' => 50,
               }
         }
```

Comment: Can you simplify the question and just show what is the expected output in Ruby?  Also, it is not clear whether it is a Ruby question or PHP question?

Comment: Indeed I'm sorry, I've added the expected ruby ouput. I'll try to simplify it now

Comment: That expected output is not valid Ruby, the outter hash must have some keys

Comment: Ok, can this key be an auto-incremented integer ?

Comment: @VilleneuveMichaël: it seems to me that you need an array and not a hash. In ruby, unlike PHP, those are different things.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Maybe, but I thought arrays could not be associative, can I put hashes into arrays ?

Comment: You can put hashes into arrays, yes. There are no "associative arrays" in ruby, yes.

Comment: Oh ok I think I get the logic, make it an answer :). Sorry for the bad explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think PHP's array/hash duality confuses you. A "hash with auto-incrementing keys" would be just an array in ruby. You can access its elements by their index (which is naturally auto-incremented).

```
result = elements.map do |element|
  {
    'title' => element['title'],
    # ...
  }
end

result # [{'title' => 'foo'}, {'title' => 'bar'}, ...]
result[0] # {'title' => 'foo'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope below is the solution that you are looking for.

```
output_hash = {}
elements.each_with_index do |element, index|
 item = {}
 item[:title] = element['title']
 item[:content] = element['content']
 item[:mark] = element['mark']
 output_hash["#{index}"] = item
end
```

**Result**

```
{"0"=>{:title=>"blabla", :content=>"blabla", :mark=>50}, 
 "1"=>{:title=>"blabla", :content=>"blabla", :mark=>50}}
```

Comment: Why the stringified index?

Comment: To make it easy to access.

Comment: How is it easier than the number?

Comment: I simply gave an indexing.

Comment: Yeah, I mean, the keys could have been integers, not strings.